# Massive number of "SET autocommit=0/1" queries in MySQL

Tags: java, mysql, database, hibernate, hikaricp

I'm running some load tests on our system and I notice a massive number of "SET autocommit=0" and "SET autocommit=1" queries being executed. Something around 25,000 within 1 minute. I'm trying to figure out what is causing this and how to get rid of it.

We use the following technologies:

- MySQL
- Hibernate
- Hikari
- Spring
- Tomcat

I have tried the following but it did not seem to help:

- "SET autocommit = 0" in MySQL
- Added the elideSetAutoCommits property in the db connection URL. "jdbc:mysql://localhost/db_name?useUniCode=true&characterEncoding=UTF-8&pinGlobalTxToPhysicalConnection=true&elideSetAutoCommits=true"

Could someone point me towards what might be causing these queries?

Comment: just a guess: can it be that Hibernate issues these "set autocommit" before and after a transaction? You can perhaps try to find out, debugging the application and noting which commands exactly arrive on the MySQL connection.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

> Could someone point me towards what might be causing these queries?

Your queries are the consequence of [`Connection#setAutoCommit(boolean)`](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/8/docs/api/java/sql/Connection.html#setAutoCommit-boolean-) which is used to switch from the default mode that is **auto-commit mode** to **transactional mode** in order to `insert/update/delete/read` data within a transaction.

The common code is :

```
// Switch to transactional mode which actually triggers a SET autocommit = 0
con.setAutoCommit(false);
try {
    // Some operations on the db
    con.commit();
} finally {
    // Switch back to auto-commit mode which actually triggers a SET autocommit = 1
    con.setAutoCommit(true);
}
```

Here is a good link that explains [how transactions work in `JDBC`](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/tutorial/jdbc/basics/transactions.html).

---

If you know that your pool of connections will always be used to get connections in transactional mode, you can set the default mode in the configuration of `Hikari` thanks to the parameter `autoCommit` to set to `false` this way the connections will be already in transactional mode such that it won't be needed anymore to modify the mode.

> This property controls the default auto-commit behavior of connections
>   returned from the pool. It is a boolean value. Default: `true`

More details about the configuration of `Hikari` [here](https://github.com/brettwooldridge/HikariCP/wiki/Configuration).

Comment: after setting suggested hikari property autoCommit to false SET autocommit=1 repeated query stopped but I am still getting SET autocommit=0 query repeatedly.